Environment Not Triggering onChange
This is my Binding Router. I want to pop to root and set 2 different bools if necessary. I want to use those bools to show a toast message. Unfortunately, even though I can set those bools to true inside BindingRouter and see their change inside PersonalAddressSettingsPage too. PersonalView can not detect this change. By catching the change I am trying to set showDeletedSuccessToastMessage and showSavedSuccessToastMessage to true so my toast message modifier is triggered.
@MainActor
final class BindingRouter: ObservableObject {
    @Binding private var popToRootValue: Bool
    
    @Published var showFirstToastMessage: Bool
    @Published var showSecondToastMessage: Bool
    
    init(_ popToRootValue: Binding<Bool> = .constant(false),
         showFirstToastMessage: Bool = false,
         showSecondToastMessage: Bool = false) {
        self._popToRootValue = popToRootValue
        self.showFirstToastMessage = showFirstToastMessage
        self.showSecondToastMessage = showSecondToastMessage
    }
    
    func popToRoot(showFirstToastMessage: Bool? = nil, showSecondToastMessage: Bool? = nil) {
        self.popToRootValue = false
        self.showFirstToastMessage = showFirstToastMessage ?? false
        self.showSecondToastMessage = showSecondToastMessage ?? false
    }
    
    func clearToastMessages() {
        showFirstToastMessage = false
        showSecondToastMessage = false
    }
}

    struct PersonalAddressSettingsPage: View {
 @EnvironmentObject private var router: BindingRouter
     .onChange(of: vm.willMoveToSuccessPage) { newValue in
                guard newValue else {
                    return
                }
                if newValue {
                    router.popToRoot(showFirstToastMessage: true) 

-> when I add a new address here is triggered as expected
 }
    }
    .onChange(of: vm.isDeleted) { newValue in
        guard newValue else {
            return
        }
        if newValue {
            router.popToRoot(showSecondToastMessage: true) 

-> when I delete an address here is triggered as expected too
}
}
I want to catch change in PersonalView but here it never triggers neither onChange nor onRecieve
   struct PersonalView: View {
 @EnvironmentObject private var router: BindingRouter
     .ndToastMessageModifier(isPresented: $showSavedSuccessToastMessage,
                                    position: .bottom,
                                    toastMessageModel: NDToastMessageModel(title: pLoc.labelText("addressSaved"),
                                                                           type: .success))
            .onReceive(router.$showFirstToastMessage) { showToast in
                if showToast {
                    self.showSavedSuccessToastMessage = true
                }
            }
            .ndToastMessageModifier(isPresented: $showDeletedSuccessToastMessage,
                                    position: .bottom,
                                    toastMessageModel: NDToastMessageModel(title: pLoc.labelText("addressDeleted"),
                                                                           type: .success))
            .onChange(of: router.showSecondToastMessage) { showToast in
                if showToast {
                    self.showDeletedSuccessToastMessage = true
                }
            } 

This is how I call PersonalView inside MainProfile
@StateObject var bindingRouter = BindingRouter()
     NavigationLink(
                            destination: PersonalView().environmentObject(bindingRouter),
                            isActive: $viewModel.goToProfileDetail
                        ) {}
                            .environmentObject(bindingRouter)


Binding is only for SwiftUI View they dont work in a class

Note, do not use @Binding in your class, as already mentioned, it is only for use in a View.
So try @Published var popToRootValue: Bool instead, and remove the init() stuff.
Use $ when you need it to be used as a binding.
Note also, in your MainProfile, there is no need for two .environmentObject(bindingRouter) the last one is enough.

I have tried with Published before but didn’t work out too. The only thing that worked so far is adding a view model as an environment object in app class
